# Never believe anything because any other person has believed it

Tags: grammar

Are there any grammar errors in this sentence? 'Never believe anything because any other person has believed it.' Thank you~

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't see any grammar mistake; however, you could help the reader or listener adding *just* and *before*:

> Never believe anything **just** because any other person has believed it **before**.

Comment: I think it is much better now.